# How to embed JSBIN code to a wordpress blog?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

when i tried to embed a JSBIN code in my WordPress blog it is not visible.Only it shows a hyperlink.
can somebody help me here?

Code I am using is as follows:

```
<a class="jsbin-embed" href="http://jsbin.com/biyozi/1/embed?html,console">ABCD</a><script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

The WordPress page can be found in the below link:
[page link](http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2015/02/lodash-pluck-and-where-method-example.html/)

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class `jsbin-embed` to your link.

```html
<a class="jsbin-embed" href="http://jsbin.com/biyozi/1/embed?html,console">ABCD</a>
<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

**Why does this work?**

The jsbin embed script looks through your page for all links that have at least one class that starts with `jsbin-`. It then checks these links (one at a time) to see if they have the class `jsbin-scoop` - if not, it then checks to see if they have the class `jsbin-embed`. If the class `jsbin-embed` is present, the embedding happens (the iframe is added, and inherits the id and classes from the link).

The embedding doc mentioned in a comment in the script (https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/docs/embedding.md) contains an example that also has the class `jsbin` on the link, though (for now, at least) the script does not do anything with this class.